# How to split output from looping into four columns

Tags: go

I want the results of my program code output to be divided into 4 columns as shown below.
[image: this is example of output]

this my code :

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var data int
    
    fmt.Scan(&data)
    
    for i := 1; i <= data; i++ {
        fmt.Println("VA", i)
    }
}
```

what should i add in my code?

Comment: You could try and search for a solution first. The problem you describe should be quite easy to find a solution to. Searching and failing will also help you in the future to be more accurate in your search terms.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const L = 4
    data := make([]int, L)

    for {
        for i := 0; i < L; i++ {
            _, err := fmt.Scan(&data[i])
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
        }

        for _, i := range data {
            fmt.Printf("VA%d ", i)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example below as a reference ([source](http://networkbit.ch/golang-column-print/)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/tabwriter"
)

func main() {
    
    // initialize tabwriter
    w := new(tabwriter.Writer)
    
    // minwidth, tabwidth, padding, padchar, flags
    w.Init(os.Stdout, 8, 8, 0, '\t', 0)
    
    defer w.Flush()
    
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n %s\t%s\t%s\t", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n %s\t%s\t%s\t", "----", "----", "----")
    
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n %d\t%d\t%d\t", i, i+1, i+2)
        }
    
     // Col1    Col2    Col3    
     // ----    ----    ----    
     // 0       1       2   
     // 1       2       3   
     // 2       3       4   
     // 3       4       5   
     // 4       5       6
}
```

Your question does not show much research though. I just googled it quickly and found the example above.